"IdentityServicePackage" Visual Studio 2022 keeps crashing after display the message couldn't load "IdentityServicePackage"
When I launch VS 2022, it displays the following two message shown on the screen shots below, then displays the initial VS screen for a couple of seconds, then crashes. I am including the activitylog.xml file as well. Please help.
Windows up to date with all updates. I tried almost every single solution listed online to no avail.Screenshot1
Screenshot2
  <entry>
    <record>391</record>
    <time>2024/07/23 01:30:12.977</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VS/Subscriptions/SetDiamondVisibility</source>
    <description>Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.DiscoveryServiceFailedException: Failed to start host &apos;dotnet$VSDetouredHost&apos;. Host exited with code &apos;-2147450745&apos; (ErrorKind: HostExited) (ErrorKind: HostExited HResult: 80131500) (ErrorKind: DiscoveryServiceFailed HResult: 80131500) (ErrorKind: DiscoveryServiceFailed HResult: 80131500)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.RemoteServiceBrokerWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass9_0.&lt;&lt;RequestServiceChannelAsync&gt;b__0&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.Shared.ServiceHubRetry.&lt;ExecuteAsync&gt;d__0`1.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.Shared.ServiceHubRetry.&lt;ExecuteAsync&gt;d__0`1.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.RemoteServiceBrokerWrapper.&lt;RequestServiceChannelAsync&gt;d__9.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.RemoteServiceBrokerWrapper.&lt;RequestServiceChannelAsync&gt;d__9.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Framework.RemoteServiceBroker.&lt;GetPipeAsync&gt;d__35.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.&lt;GetPipeAsync&gt;d__39.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.ServiceBrokerPipeManager.&lt;HookJsonRpcAsync&gt;d__9.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.ServiceBrokerPipeManager.&lt;HookJsonRpcAsync&gt;d__9.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.ServiceBrokerPipeManager.&lt;GetReconnectionTaskAsync&gt;d__5.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.PipeManager.&lt;RepairConnectionAsync&gt;d__19.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.ServiceBrokerPipeManager.&lt;InitializeAsync&gt;d__7.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.ServiceBrokerPipeManager.&lt;CreateAsync&gt;d__4.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.StorageService.StorageServiceClient.&lt;InitializeAsync&gt;d__16.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.StorageService.StorageServiceClient.&lt;CreateAsync&gt;d__15.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountManager.&lt;GetStoreAsync&gt;d__33.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.Packages.Subscriptions.VsSubscriptionsBenefitsBroker.&lt;GetUserBenefitsAsync&gt;d__6.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.Packages.Subscriptions.DiamondControl.&lt;SetDiamondVisibilityAsync&gt;d__7.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskLibraryHelper.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;&lt;FileAndForget&gt;b__35_0&gt;d.MoveNext()</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>392</record>
    <time>2024/07/23 01:30:13.003</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [IdentityServicePackage]Source: &apos;Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client&apos; Description: Failed to start host &apos;dotnet$VSDetouredHost&apos;. Host exited with code &apos;-2147450745&apos; (ErrorKind: HostExited) (ErrorKind: HostExited HResult: 80131500) (ErrorKind: DiscoveryServiceFailed HResult: 80131500) (ErrorKind: DiscoveryServiceFailed HResult: 80131500)&#x000D;&#x000A;Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.DiscoveryServiceFailedException: Failed to start host &apos;dotnet$VSDetouredHost&apos;. Host exited with code &apos;-2147450745&apos; (ErrorKind: HostExited) (ErrorKind: HostExited HResult: 80131500) (ErrorKind: DiscoveryServiceFailed HResult: 80131500) (ErrorKind: DiscoveryServiceFailed HResult: 80131500)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.RemoteServiceBrokerWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass9_0.&lt;&lt;RequestServiceChannelAsync&gt;b__0&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.Shared.ServiceHubRetry.&lt;ExecuteAsync&gt;d__0`1.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.Shared.ServiceHubRetry.&lt;ExecuteAsync&gt;d__0`1.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.RemoteServiceBrokerWrapper.&lt;RequestServiceChannelAsync&gt;d__9.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.RemoteServiceBrokerWrapper.&lt;RequestServiceChannelAsync&gt;d__9.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Framework.RemoteServiceBroker.&lt;GetPipeAsync&gt;d__35.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.&lt;GetPipeAsync&gt;d__39.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.ServiceBrokerPipeManager.&lt;HookJsonRpcAsync&gt;d__9.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.ServiceBrokerPipeManager.&lt;HookJsonRpcAsync&gt;d__9.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.ServiceBrokerPipeManager.&lt;GetReconnectionTaskAsync&gt;d__5.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.PipeManager.&lt;RepairConnectionAsync&gt;d__19.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.ServiceBrokerPipeManager.&lt;InitializeAsync&gt;d__7.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.ServiceBrokerPipeManager.&lt;CreateAsync&gt;d__4.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.StorageService.StorageServiceClient.&lt;InitializeAsync&gt;d__16.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.StorageService.StorageServiceClient.&lt;CreateAsync&gt;d__15.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.StorageServiceClientFactory.&lt;GetStorageClientAsync&gt;d__0.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AwaitExtensions.ExecuteContinuationSynchronouslyAwaiter`1.GetResult()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AsyncLazy`1.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass20_0.&lt;&lt;GetValueAsync&gt;b__0&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProviders.CachingStorageClientFactory.&lt;GetStorageClientAsync&gt;d__4.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.IdentityService.Composition.CompositionRootDirector.&lt;CreateAccountAwareInteractionLayerAsync&gt;d__6.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.IdentityService.Composition.CompositionRootDirector.&lt;BuildAsync&gt;d__0.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.IdentityService.IdentityServicePackage.&lt;InitializeAsync&gt;d__2.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass21_0.&lt;&lt;Microsoft-VisualStudio-Shell-Interop-IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize-Initialize&gt;b__1&gt;d.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)</description>
    <guid>{C35E0ABB-7F17-447F-B054-7B73D6D7581D}</guid>
    <hr>0x80131500</hr>
    <errorinfo></errorinfo>
  </entry>

I tried to follow all pervious posts about VS 2022 crashing to no avail.
Uninstalled and installed VS 2022 and also the preview version

as I looked through the error message error id 135 indicates coreclr library missing and this can be fixed by reinstalling windows.You can try resetting your pc and see if the problem still exists.
